# How to setup latex extension on Adobe Brackets?

Tags: compiling, editors

I use Adobe Brackets for most of my coding. Recently, I decided to do my latex coding on Brackets as well. Luckily, someone has come up with a [solution](https://github.com/thehogfather/brackets-latex). The extension for Brackets is very easy to install.

However, I have a hard time figuring out how to compile my latex files within Brackets. Has anyone figured this out yet?

When I compile, I get this message: "usr/texbin/dflatex No such file or directory" and I have tried to change the directory but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome! What's Adobe Brackets?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is usually too vague to be of much help. What doesn't work? The editor? the place where you tried to type "it" won't let you? you typed the wrong thing? your computer caught on fire? etc., etc.  And have you tried contacting the person -- thehogfather -- who made the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have downloaded and installed “brackets-latex”, open the preferences and modify the `brackets.json` file shown on the right pane so it contains the last line

```json
{
    "fonts.fontSize": "18px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "brackets-latex.texBinDirectory": "/Library/TeX/texbin"
}
```

[image]

The initial lines are what I had by default (I only changed `12px` to `18px`)

Save and compile.

Comment: Thanks. That actually worked and fixed the problem. I think that's a problem with the new Mac OS Sierra. I now have another problem with pdflatex. I get this error "There was an error executing the command "/Library/Tex/texbin/pdflatex"

Comment: @A.Hada Check two things: the X in TeX should be uppercase; at http://tug.org/mactex you find something about MacTeX and Sierra